# What is the purpose of the for(... : ...) loop in copying an array

Tags: java, arrays

When I go through a tutorial I found this code.. but one place of following code I cannot understand

Can anyone describe what happen from following part

```
for(String old : oldArray){
    System.out.println(old);
}
```

This is full code....

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] oldArray = {"one","two"};
        String[] newArray = oldArray;

        newArray[0]= "three";

        for(String old : oldArray){
            System.out.println(old);
        }

        System.out.println("");

        for(String latest : oldArray){
            System.out.println(latest);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you *run* it to see what it does?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Your code does not make a *copy* of the array.  But then again, you are never using `newArray` anyway.

Comment: @CommuSoft Are you sure your edit reflects the OP's intent?  If we suppose that the second loop should actually iterate over `newArray`, then this might be a demo to show that copying a reference to an array does not copy the array.  But if you are sure this is not what the question is all about, you should probably remove the *arracopy* tag as well.

Comment: @5gon12eder: well the original title suggest help with copying an array. But the question states: *Can anyone describe what happen from following part* which is a `for(... : ...)` construct.

Comment: Thanks for everyone comments.. sorry for poor title :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that this

```
for(String old : oldArray){
    System.out.println(old);
}
```

does is to loop through the entries of `oldArray` printing them out one by one. It's equivalent to

```
for (int i=0; i<oldArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(oldArray[i]);
}
```

The code you've put up doesn't do any array copying at all.

Comment: Why the downvote? It answers the question exactly.

Comment: You equal to a enumerator, but its more like an an iterator.

Comment: @PeterRader The code does the same thing, and it uses language features that OP is more likely to be familiar with. It is by far the easiest way of explaining a for-each loop.

Comment: You could even change "old" to something more descriptive like "oldRow". Just a detail but makes it a little bit more clear.

Comment: @chiastic-security Now you removed the comparisation with enumerator in your edit, so i upvote.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [*for-each*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) loop in Java. It is a short version of iterating over all elements in the array.

What you thus do is iterating over the array and printing each of the elements.

I think in this context it is merely used to validate whether the output is correct.

Ironically enough, the code doesn't perform array copying at all.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] oldArray = {"one","two"};
    String[] wrongCopy = oldArray;
    String[] correctCopy = (String[]) oldArray.clone();

    for(String xi : oldArray){
        System.out.println(xi);
    }
    System.out.println("---");
    for(String xi : wrongCopy){
        System.out.println(xi);
    }
    System.out.println("---");
    for(String xi : correctCopy){
        System.out.println(xi);
    }

    System.out.println("--- after modifications ---");

    wrongCopy[0]= "three";
    oldArray[1]= "four";

    for(String xi : oldArray){
        System.out.println(xi);
    }
    System.out.println("---");
    for(String xi : wrongCopy){
        System.out.println(xi);
    }
    System.out.println("---");
    for(String xi : correctCopy){
        System.out.println(xi);
    }

}
```

[**jdoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/ic).

As you can see, if you modify the elements of the `oldArray` and `wrongCopy`, they appear on "both" arrays. Whereas the `.clone()` makes an actual duplicate of the array that is not sensible to modifications from its parent.